# Absolute Path of a Local File Object

Tags: java, file, path

so I'm looking towards porting a .jar to an executable and am cleaning my code up a bit before I do that. Right now I have the following:

```
BufferedImage bgImg = null;
//Grabs the background image
    try {
        bgImg = ImageIO.read(new File(""));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have several other images that I can just use:

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("imagename.png")));
```

However, since the former is a File object it does not take the same type of argument. I was wondering if there is something similar that I can use for that, or if there is some other way to make the File absolute so that there are no errors when porting to an executable. Thanks!

Comment: An empty file name will certainly not work. Where is the file going to be? Do you have a way of knowing the path of the file? Is it always going to be in the same directory? Or is it going to be in a directory relative to something you know?

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, before that I had that filled with a few things (i.e. failed attempts to access the file using a relative directory, just the name of the file, etc.). I originally had it with the exact path to my desktop, but I moved it to a folder on the project's working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `read(InputStream input)` method instead with `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.

For example:

```
bgImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("imagename.png"));
```

Comment: This works also. Looking back now that makes more sense (since I was using that in the parameters of new File()).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to do. But you can access a file in your current working directory with a dot before the path.

E.g.

```
ImageIO.read(new File("./imagename.png"));
```

Comment: That pretty much put me on the right path, it's working as intended now!

Comment: @finaris `./` will be relative to which ever directory the user runs the code from, unless you change the working directory first. From a portability point of view, you're better using `getResources*` methods which will use the classpath instead

Comment: @finaris Alastair is right. What do you meen by 'porting to an executable'? An executable jar (then you can use classpath resources as before)? Or a non-java executable? In the second case most programming languages give you an argument-array (like in the java main). Sometimes you can access the path of your executable at index 0.

Comment: Yeah, I had meant to convert my existing classes into a single .jar and use launch4j to convert that to a native windows executable (which thanks to you guys I've now done successfully lol). Either solution worked, it was just that I needed to remove a relative path from my system into something that was more direct into the project.